# flipping an image in ms paint using sendkeys

Tags: batch-file

I have been trying to make a bat file that flips the current image in ms paint, (by pressing alt, i, alt, i, f, enter) but no matter what I do, it can only get to the point of pressing alt i:

```
 powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%%{i}%')"
 powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%%{i}%')"
 powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('f')"
```

I have tried this, it only gets up to pressing the equivalent of alt i then stops.
The full code is this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

REM Minimize the active window
powershell -c "Add-Type -TypeDefinition 'using System; using System.Runtime.InteropServices; public class WindowState { [DllImport(\"user32.dll\")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow); [DllImport(\"user32.dll\")] public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow(); }'; [WindowState]::ShowWindowAsync([WindowState]::GetForegroundWindow(), 2)"

prtscreen key

powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^{PRTSC}')"

open ms

open cmd

explorer.exe Shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}

powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('mspaint')"                       

REM Simulate pressing the Enter key
powershell -c "Add-Type -TypeDefinition 'using System; using System.Runtime.InteropServices; public class KeyPresser { [DllImport(\"user32.dll\")] public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo); }'; [KeyPresser]::keybd_event(0x0D, 0, 0, [UIntPtr]::Zero); [KeyPresser]::keybd_event(0x0D, 0, 2, [UIntPtr]::Zero);"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('')"  

REM timeout /t <5> [/nobreak]
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^v')"
REM timeout /t <3> [/nobreak]
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%%{i}%')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%%{i}%')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('f')"

powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{ENTER}')"
pause
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^s')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}')" 
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(' ')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('C:\Users\olive\Pictures')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{ENTER}')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}')"
powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{ENTER}')"
timeout /t <150> [/nobreak]
REM start %USERPROFILE%\desktop\openpicture.bat
REM start C:\Users\olive\Pictures\untitled.png
SLEEP 30

powershell -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^r')"

endlocal
pause
```

Comment: Why do you not install a program which supports what you want to do from the command line with appropriate command line options? For example, *IrfanView* is a multimedia viewer being freeware for private usage which supports lots of command line options documented in text file `i_options.txt` like `/hflip` for a horizontal flip and `/vflip` for a vertical flip. *ImageMagick* is another free and additionally open-source application which supports such image processing from the command line.

Comment: my plan is to have all of this as a bat file,which then sets the flipped image is the wallpaper then flips the computers display180 degrees, making it look normal but everything seems to be upside down. then i will use bat2exe to change thumbnail to a .docx file then send it to an email scammer and have them open it thinking it is personal information

Answer (score 0):

Déjà-vu. For me the effect wasn't so great but funny to see what happens. If you want to implement your plan, good luck...

The following batch (more like powershell) uses the trick of setting a variable with newlines <cr><lf> and passing it to ps. All lines with an @ are filtered beforehand.

That's not really useful for what you're trying to do. I would recommend embedding a base64 encoded variant in the batch. That would even make it a one-liner.

Not practical for testing and reading the code... ;)

```ps1
@ECHO OFF
@ENDLOCAL
@SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@REM -> Creating a Line Feed variable (the blank lines are required!)
@SET LF=^


@REM <- The two empty lines are neccessary, spaces are not allowed!
@SET command=#
@FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('findstr -bv @ "%~f0"') DO SET command=!command!!LF!%%A
@powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -noprofile -command !command! & EXIT /B


# *** POWERSHELL CODE STARTS HERE *** #
Add-Type -TypeDefinition '
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class WindowState {
[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]
public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
}
';
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
[WindowState]::ShowWindowAsync([WindowState]::GetForegroundWindow(), 2)
Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 200;
$Screen  = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen
$Width   = $Screen.Width
$Height  = $Screen.Height
$Left    = $Screen.Left
$Top     = $Screen.Top
$bitmap  = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $Width, $Height
$graphic = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bitmap)
$graphic.CopyFromScreen($Left, $Top, 0, 0, $bitmap.Size)
$bitmap.RotateFlip([System.Drawing.RotateFlipType]::Rotate180FlipY)
$bitmap.Save($env:TEMP + '\sc.bmp')
$setwallpapersrc = '
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Wallpaper {
public const int SetDesktopWallpaper = 20;
public const int UpdateIniFile = 0x01;
public const int SendWinIniChange = 0x02;
[DllImport(\"user32.dll\", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);
public static void SetWallpaper(string path) {
SystemParametersInfo(SetDesktopWallpaper, 0, path, UpdateIniFile | SendWinIniChange);
}
}
'
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $setwallpapersrc
[Wallpaper]::SetWallpaper($env:TEMP + '\sc.bmp')
Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 100;
$x = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application;
$x.minimizeall()
```

The reason for your script do not work (as far as I see it wasn't even close to do what it should) is escaping `%%`. You maybe should store the % inside a var like set `Percent=%%` and then `%Percent%`.

Comment: Hello, I have tried that code, there is 2 problems with it that my tiny brain can't seem to solve. first off, when it sets the image as the wallpaper, the image is not just flipped, but also inverted, and secondly, it enlarges the image slightly. It would be a big help if you could walk me through the steps to fix it. thanks. I would like to thank you for how well you made that code.

Comment: @bobby 1.: Change `$bitmap.RotateFlip([System.Drawing.RotateFlipType]::Rotate180FlipY)` according https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rotatefliptype?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0 2.: Hard to say. Do you have multiple screens? I see no reason because `Screen.Height` and `Screen.Width` should fit. Maybe the taskbar?

Comment: I have tried taking a screenshot with and without the taskbar, the taskbar dosent actually show up, which is odd.